# Conditional expectation of $X$ given $X\neq 0$

Tags: probability

Let $p_0=P(X=0)$ and $0<p_0<1$. Let $\mu=E[X]$ and $\sigma^2= \text{Var}(X)$. Find $E(X\mid X \neq 0)$ and $\text{Var}(X\mid X \neq 0)$.

Is it right to use double expectation property?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Users are reluctant to address information in images;consider converting to text. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is this "double expectation property" that you want to use?

Comment: is it right to use “E(x)=E(E(X|Y)) “ property???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the obvious solution with a few basic details.

Let $A = \{\omega: X(\omega) \neq 0 \}$. For short, we say that $A$ is the event that $X\neq 0$ and $p(A) = 1-p_0$. Then,

$$
\mu = E(X)=E(E(X | A))= E(X|A)P(A)+E(X|A^c)P(A^c)=E(X|A)P(A),
$$

where $P(A^c)=1-P(A)$.

Note that the event $A^c$ means that $X=0$, hence the second term above is zero.

Then, $\mu=E(X|A)P(A)$ so that $E(X|X\neq 0) = \mu/(1-p_0)$

We find $V(X|A)$ in a similar way. First note that $\sigma^2 = V(X)=E(X^2)-(EX)^2$, thus $E(X^2) = \sigma^2+\mu^2$. Then,

$$
E(X^2)=E(E(X^2 | A))= E(X^2|A)P(A)+E(X^2|A^c)P(A^c)=E(X^2|A)P(A),
$$

so that $E(X^2|A)P(A) = (\sigma^2+\mu^2)/(1-p_0)$.

Comment: thank u so much !!!!! and do you know how to calculate variance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible. We know then that,
$$
E(E(X \, | \, X \neq0)) = \mu
$$
and further,
$$
E(E(X \, | \, X \neq0)) = E(X\,|\, X \neq0)P(X\neq0)
$$
should be straightforward from here.